# React Bootstrap change link of Navbar to active

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, navbar

I use a Navbar as a component on page, which uses Router to change the content. Everything is working fine, so far. But I can´t figure out, how I can set the state of the links in the Navbar to active, when they are clicked. I think, I have to bind the activeKey of the Nav element to the location.pathname of the active content.

This is my Navbar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Navbar extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          show: false
        };
      }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                    <Navbar.Brand >Filmmusic</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav activeKey="/" className="mr-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link onClick = {()=>{this.handleModal()}}>Contact</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav>
                        <Nav.Link href="/impressum">Impressum</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/datenschutzerklaerung">Datenschutzerklärung</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks a lot! Everything is working fine now :) I wrote the Navbar code into the index.js, instead of using a component. And I put all components below the Router element. Here is the final code of my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { About } from './components/About';
import { Contact } from './components/Contact';
import { NoMatch } from './components/NoMatch';
import { Impressum } from './components/Impressum';
import { Datenschutzerklaerung } from './components/Datenschutzerklaerung';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Jumbotron } from './components/Jumbotron';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import './fontawesome';
import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const Header = props => {
  const { location } = props;
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Navbar.Brand >Filmmusic</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
      <Nav activeKey={location.pathname} className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
      <Nav activeKey={location.pathname}>
          <Nav.Link href="/impressum">Impressum</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/datenschutzerklaerung">Datenschutzerklärung</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
  );
};
const HeaderWithRouter = withRouter(Header);

class MyHeader extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
        <HeaderWithRouter />
        <Jumbotron />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Layout>
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              <Route path="/impressum" component={Impressum} />
              <Route path="/datenschutzerklaerung" component={Datenschutzerklaerung} />
            </Layout>
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Footer />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyHeader />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the router and need more flexibility in your state change, you can also use the `useState` hook:

```js
export const Nav = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('default');
  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        className="sub-nav"
        activeKey={active}
        onSelect={(selectedKey) => setActive(selectedKey)}
      >
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="default">Default</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Link 1</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Link 2</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="disabled" disabled>
            Disabled
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your `NavBar` component with `withRouter` HOC. Then you can make these changes:

```
render(){
    const { location } = props;  //add this
    return(
        <div>
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Navbar.Brand >Filmmusic</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav activeKey={location.pathname} className="mr-auto"> //Update this
                    <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link onClick = {()=>{this.handleModal()}}>Contact</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/impressum">Impressum</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/datenschutzerklaerung">Datenschutzerklärung</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    )
}
```

More details about [withRouter HOC](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to use withRouter. I have to implement the Navbar in the index.js file, right? I tried it, like it´s shown here https://codesandbox.io/s/718p1ovkm1?file=/src/index.js:86-132 but I got this error message: Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Header) /> outside a <Router>

Comment: Yes, you have to wrap your `NavBar` component with `BrowserRouter` before wrapping it with `withRouter`.

As you mentioned you tried that, have you noticed one thing they have wrapped `HeaderWithRouter` inside `Router` in `App` component.

Answer (score 0):

`withRouter` is deprecated since `react-router` v5.1

So you can just use location hook.

```
const location = useLocation();
  ...
    <Nav activeKey={location.pathname} className="mr-auto">
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a mix of both `as={Link} to{"/" href="#"` to get the active style to work:

```
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/"} href="#">
                  <span className={styles.ddlink}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={myIcons['house']} fontSize="1.0rem" />&nbsp;&nbsp;HOME</span>
                </Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/resume"} href="#resume">
                  <span className={styles.ddlink}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={myIcons['book']} fontSize="1.0rem" />&nbsp;&nbsp;RESUME</span>
                </Nav.Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this three rules:

1.Use useLocation to get active path.

2.Use activeKey={location.pathname} in Nav component.

---

```
const Header = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
    return (
      <Navbar  activeKey={location.pathname} collapseOnSelect expand='lg' bg="light" variant="light" className='shadow-sm'>
        <Container className='fw-bold '>
          <Navbar.Brand className='fs-1' href="#home">Let's Learn</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav" className='lg-d-flex justify-content-end'>
            <Nav activeKey={location.pathname}>
              <Nav.Link className='me-5' href="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link className='me-5' href="/blog">Blog</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link className='me-5' href="/services">Statistics</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link className='me-5' href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    );
}
```

3.In CSS file write active color like:

```
.active{
    color: blue!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every solutions above, but either need to downgrade `react-router`, change your code destructively, or does not work due to re-render, finally I found the perfect solution that needs no changes to your current code, just use `window.location.pathname`.

```js
<Nav activeKey={window.location.pathname}>
 // <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

Then, cheers!